# gtsumamry package - Is it normal that it takes too much time to run?

Tags: gtsummary

I am currently running the tbl_uvregression on a dataset with 413,177 rows and 6 columns. When I try to run it, it says I do not have enough memory for it to work (I've expanded memory size limit to no avail).

I consequently narrowed it to a subset of the first 1000 rows, just to try it out, but it's taking an awfully long time to generate it (currently 30 mins +). Is this normal for such a large dataset? Or is there something wrong in the code?

**The code example I'm using is as follows. (df = datframe)**

```
univ_tab <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(explanatory_vars, outcome) ## select variables of interest

univ_tab <- univ_tab[1:1000,]

univ_tab <- univ_tab %>%  
  tbl_uvregression(                         
    method = glm,                          
    y = outcome,                            
    method.args = list(family = binomial),  
    exponentiate = TRUE                     
  )
```

Comment: its hard to know if this is a `gtsummary` issue or a issue with the data/ your computer. can you share at least some of the data so we can see if there is a glaring issue? did you remove the id column from the dataset before feeding it into `tbl_uvregression`

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for this. Interestingly I took up your idea to remove id - the computer insisted it remains for some reason. So I changed the id from a normal ID number to a simple index and it worked. Is there any particular reason for this? The ID usually is a series of 7 numbers followed by a letter.

Comment: if you are feeding the ID with ~400k rows to `tbl_uvregression`, it will try to fit a lm on your ID with 400k unique levels (one for each id) this will crash your computer. you might not be able to remove ID beforehand if you are working with grouped data, try to `ungroup()` before using tbl_uvregression, just a guess though

Comment: Thank you Mike. I actually removed ID and it worked smoothly. I didn't know the tbl_uvregression function would be considering IDs as something to run in an lm. I did as suggested - ungrouped, removed the ID, and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: `tbl_uvregression()` will try to fit a model for every variable passed to it that isn't specified as the outcome. It doesn't determine ID columns for the user. But glad the suggestion worked!